# Outlook 2010 and IMAP

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, gmail, imap

I have a work Exchange account that sits in Outlook and a personal Google Apps account that I have setup as IMAP.

My problem is that without having the IMAP inbox open email doesn't push to Outlook, and it only comes through at every send/receive pass. My workaround is to open the IMAP inbox in a new window but is there a better way?

Comment: I'm not sure if I can PM you or not, but do you still have this issue? I have it as well. Thanks.

Comment: Hey Mate, 

Yes still an issue. Even after upgrading to Outlook 2013. 
My workaround is to have my imap inbox open on a new window that just sits minimised. Works well,

Cheers,
Dave